# Elasticsearch Not getting consistence record

Tags: php, elasticsearch

We are not using mapping for elastic search and we are trying to search using wildcard search. It's not returning the consistence data. There is any suggestion how we can maintain the consistency.
Below is the snippet, how we are currently fetching data:

```
          "should": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "( *firskeyword* ) ( *secondKeyword* )",
                        "default_operator": "AND",
                        "fields": [
                            "building_name",
                            "name_first",
                            "name_last",
                            "name_middle",
                            "email_address",...
```

Comment: can you please explain your question, in terms of what result are you getting now, and your expected search result ?

Comment: Every time I hit this Query the result is different means it's not consistent. Suppose I am searching 'ESCoder One' then first time it will return EsCoder One, EsCoder Two etc. But next time I hit the same query the order is not same it might return EsCoder Two, EsCoder One and etc.. I want to keep result same everytime I hit the Query.

Comment: Or please suggest, what practices should I follow? to achieve the same result.